# How it feels walking to the end of flat earth?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, earth

I have seen a video on YouTube on channel Vsauce about the flat earth belief.

There he claims that walking to the edges of this flat earth would be difficult. Something like going up an acclivity.

Is this claim true and if yes why?

Any answer containing maths would be useful.

Comment: Will you please provide a link to the video.  [Is this the video?}(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VNqNnUJVcVs)

Comment: The video explains the reason, does it not? The gravitational field produced by the mass of the flat disk is qualitateively given by the left pane in the second figure in [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/277820/could-a-disc-have-a-gravitational-pull) post. You will notice that the arrows are more and more skewed to point towards the centre of the disk as you approach the edges. And the direction of "down" is just the direction of the gravitational field.

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of [Could a disc have a gravitational pull?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/277820/).

Comment: If you believe that the Earth is a flat disk, then you can believe anything you want about gravity. Why would it matter? If you believe that the Earth is a flat disk, then obviously you don't care whether or not there is any relationship between your personal beliefs and anything else in the world.

Comment: @SolomonSlow pity it is already answered i asked about the gravity on a turning disc you could write some nice things

Comment: @Larsaseeidaklaxtarsa, I'm sorry. I misunderstood your question. I didn't watch the video. My comment should have been directed to the video's creator. What I was trying to say, and didn't spend enough time thinking about how to say it, is that it's silly to argue against flat-Earthers by reasoning about how gravity (or any other physical phenomenon) works. If _they_ are willing to say that the Earth is flat, then _they_ can just say, "Oh, but that's not how gravity works,..." It's the old question of who's the bigger fool: Is it the fool? or is it the person who argues with the fool?